# What is the best way to test that a spring application context fails to start?

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot, spring-test

I use the spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-test.

Let's say I have a class for binding configuration properties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dummy")
public class DummyProperties {

    @URL
    private String url;

    // getter, setter ...

}
```

Now I want to test that my bean validation is correct. The context should fail to start (with a specfic error message) if the property `dummy.value` is not set or if it contains an invalid URL. The context should start if the property contains a valid URL. (The test would show that `@NotNull` is missing.)

A test class would look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@IntegrationTest({ "dummy.url=123:456" })
public class InvalidUrlTest {
    // my test code
}
```

This test would fail because the provided property is invalid. What would be the best way to tell Spring/JUnit: "yep, this error is expected". In plain JUnit tests I would use the ExpectedException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is that an integration test to begin with? Why are you starting a full blown Spring Boot app for that?

This looks like unit testing to me. That being said, you have several options:

- Don't add `@IntegrationTest` and Spring Boot will not start a web server to begin with (use `@PropertySource` to pass value to your test but it feels wrong to pass an invalid value to your whole test class)
- You can use `spring.main.web-environment=false` to disable the web server (but that's silly given the point above)
- Write a unit test that process that `DummyProperties` of yours. You don't even need to start a Spring Boot application for that. Look at [our own test suite](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/fbfbec11/spring-boot/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessorTests.java#L103)

I'd definitely go with the last one. Maybe you have a good reason to have an integration test for that?

Answer (score 20):

#### The best way to test Spring application context is to use `ApplicationContextRunner`

It is described in Spring Boot Reference Documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-test-autoconfig

And there is a quick guide about it:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-runner

#### Sample usage

```
private static final String POSITIVE_CASE_CONFIG_FILE =  
"classpath:some/path/positive-case-config.yml";
private static final String NEGATIVE_CASE_CONFIG_FILE =  
"classpath:some/path/negative-case-config.yml";

@Test
void positiveTest() {
  ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
    .withInitializer(new ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer())//1
    .withInitializer(new ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener(LogLevel.DEBUG))//2
    .withUserConfiguration(MockBeansTestConfiguration.class)//3
    .withPropertyValues("spring.config.location=" + POSITIVE_CASE_CONFIG_FILE)//4
    .withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(BookService.class));//5
  contextRunner
    .run((context) -> {
      Assertions.assertThat(context).hasNotFailed();//6
    });
}

@Test
void negativeTest() {
  ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
    .withInitializer(new ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer())//1
    .withInitializer(new ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener(LogLevel.DEBUG))//2
    .withUserConfiguration(MockBeansTestConfiguration.class)//3
    .withPropertyValues("spring.config.location=" + NEGATIVE_CASE_CONFIG_FILE)//4
    .withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(BookService.class));//5
  contextRunner
    .run((context) -> {
      assertThat(context)
        .hasFailed();
      assertThat(context.getStartupFailure())
        .isNotNull();
      assertThat(context.getStartupFailure().getMessage())
        .contains("Some exception message");
      assertThat(extractFailureCauseMessages(context))
        .contains("Cause exception message");
    });
}

private List<String> extractFailureCauseMessages(AssertableApplicationContext context) {
  var failureCauseMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
  var currentCause = context.getStartupFailure().getCause();
  while (!Objects.isNull(currentCause)) {//7
    failureCauseMessages.add(currentCause.getMessage());
    currentCause = currentCause.getCause();
  }
  return failureCauseMessages;
}
```

**Explanation with examples of similar definitions from Junit5 Spring Boot Test Annotations:**

1. Triggers loading of config files like `application.properties` or `application.yml`
2. Logs `ConditionEvaluationReport` using given log level when application context fails
3. Provides class that specifies mock beans, ie. we have `@Autowired BookRepository` in our `BookService` and we provide mock `BookRepository` in `MockBeansTestConfiguration`. Similar to `@Import({MockBeansTestConfiguration.class})` in test class and `@TestConfiguration` in class with mock beans in normal Junit5 Spring Boot Test
4. Equivalent of `@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=" + POSITIVE_CASE_CONFIG_FILE})`
5. Triggers spring auto configuration for given class, not direct equivalent, but it is similar to using `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BookService.class})` or `@SpringBootTest(classes = {BookService.class})` together with `@Import({BookService.class})` in normal test
6. Assertions.class from AssertJ library, there should be static import for `Assertions.assertThat`, but I wanted to show where this method is from
7. There should be static import for `Objects.isNull`, but I wanted to show where this method is from

**MockBeansTestConfiguration class:**

```
@TestConfiguration
public class MockBeansTestConfiguration {
  private static final Book SAMPLE_BOOK = Book.of(1L, "Stanisław Lem", "Solaris", "978-3-16-148410-0");

  @Bean
  public BookRepository mockBookRepository() {
    var bookRepository = Mockito.mock(BookRepository.class);//1
    Mockito.when(bookRepository.findByIsbn(SAMPLE_BOOK.getIsbn()))//2
           .thenReturn(SAMPLE_BOOK);
    return bookRepository;
  }
}
```

Remarks:
1,2. There should be static import, but I wanted to show where this method is from

Comment: After 5 more years of experience with Spring, `ApplicationContextRunner` is one of my favorite classes for testing. And it's really helpful for my described use case.

Comment: @RolandWeisleder I couldn't agree more, I have the same number of years of boot experience and I can't believe I never saw this class before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is:

```
public class InvalidUrlTest {

    @Rule
    public DisableOnDebug testTimeout = new DisableOnDebug(new Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expected = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void shouldFailOnStartIfUrlInvalid() {
        // configure ExpectedException
        expected.expect(...

        MyApplication.main("--dummy.url=123:456");
    }

// other cases
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but this would not work if the expected exception is not thrown. Due to the web-starter-pom the main method would start a webserver. The test would wait for the server to be shut down.

Comment: If you worry about an infinite wait (yes, it's always a good idea), you can always apply a timeout (by rule or @Timeout annotation). See updated version.