# Spring Boot Apache Camel Routes testing

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, camel-test

I have a Springboot application, where I have some Camel routes configured.

```java
public class CamelConfig {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CamelConfig.class);

    @Value("${activemq.broker.url:tcp://localhost:61616}")
    String brokerUrl;

    @Value("${activemq.broker.maxconnections:1}")
    int maxConnections;

    @Bean
    ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl));
        pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(maxConnections);
        return pooledConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RoutesBuilder route() {
        LOG.info("Initializing camel routes......................");
        return new SpringRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("activemq:testQueue")
                  .to("bean:queueEventHandler?method=handleQueueEvent");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I want to test this route from `activemq:testQueue` to `queueEventHandler::handleQueueEvent`.
I tried different things mentioned here http://camel.apache.org/camel-test.html, but doesn't seem to get it working.

I am trying to do something like this:

```java
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = {CamelConfig.class,   CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class})
    public class CamelRouteConfigTest {

    @Produce(uri = "activemq:testQueue")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("testJson", "foo", "bar");
        // Verify handleQueueEvent(...) method is called on bean queueEventHandler by mocking
    }
```

But my ProducerTemplate is always `null`. I tried auto-wiring `CamelContext`, for which I get an exception saying *it cannot resolve camelContext*. But that can be resolved by adding `SpringCamelContext.class` to `@SpringBootTest` classes. But my `ProducerTemplate` is still `null`.

Please suggest. I am using Camel 2.18 and Spring Boot 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did this finally:

```java
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class CamelRouteConfigTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CamelRouteConfigTest.class);
        private static BrokerService brokerSvc = new BrokerService();
    
        @Mock
        private QueueEventHandler queueEventHandler;
    
        @BeforeClass
        // Sets up an embedded broker
        public static void setUpBroker() throws Exception {
            brokerSvc.setBrokerName("TestBroker");
            brokerSvc.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
            brokerSvc.setPersistent(false);
            brokerSvc.setUseJmx(false);
            brokerSvc.start();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
            return new CamelConfig().route();
        }
    
        // properties in .yml has to be loaded manually. Not sure of .properties file
        @Override
        protected Properties useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent() {
            YamlPropertySourceLoader loader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
            try {
                PropertySource<?> applicationYamlPropertySource = loader.load(
                    "properties", new ClassPathResource("application.yml"),null);// null indicated common properties for all profiles.
                Map source = ((MapPropertySource) applicationYamlPropertySource).getSource();
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.putAll(source);
                return properties;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("application.yml file cannot be found.");
            }
    
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
            JndiRegistry jndi = super.createRegistry();
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            jndi.bind("queueEventHandler", queueEventHandler);
    
            return jndi;
        }
    
        @Test
        // Sleeping for a few seconds is necessary, because this line template.sendBody runs in a different thread and
        // CamelTest takes a few seconds to do the routing.
        public void testRoute() throws InterruptedException {
            template.sendBody("activemq:productpushevent", "HelloWorld!");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            verify(queueEventHandler, times(1)).handleQueueEvent(any());
        }
    
        @AfterClass
        public static void shutDownBroker() throws Exception {
            brokerSvc.stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide entire route and test code in Git?Thanks.

Comment: @pvpkiran, Thanks for sharing first of all. 

Where does the `template` come from? I am struggling with that.

Comment: @ddsultan template resolves via the CamelTestSupport class (since CamelRouteConfigTest extends CamelTestSupport)

Comment: @gurpal2000, Thank you, I will check that.

Answer (score 10):

In Camel 2.22.0 and ongoing, which supports Spring Boot 2 you can use the following template to test your routes with Spring Boot 2 support:

```java
@RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE, classes = {
    Route1.class,
    Route2.class,
    ...
})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@DisableJmx
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class RouteTest {

  @TestConfiguration
  static class Config {
    @Bean
    CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration() {
      return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
        @Override
        public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
          // configure Camel here
        }

        @Override
        public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
          // Start your manual routes here
        }
      };
    }

    @Bean
    RouteBuilder routeBuilder() {
      return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
          from("direct:someEndpoint").to("mock:done");
        }
      };
    }

    // further beans ...
  }

  @Produce(uri = "direct:start")
  private ProducerTemplate template;
  @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:done")
  private MockEndpoint mockDone;

  @Test
  public void testCamelRoute() throws Exception {
    mockDone.expectedMessageCount(1);

    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    ...
    template.sendBodyAndHeaders("test", headers);

    mockDone.assertIsSatisfied();
  }
}
```

Spring Boot distinguishes between `@Configuration` and `@TestConfiguration`. The primer one will replace any existing configuration, if annotated on a top-level class, while `@TestConfiguration` will be run in addition to the other configurations.

Further, in larger projects you might run into auto-configuration issues as you can't rely on Spring Boot 2 to configure your custom database pooling or what not correctly or in cases where you have a specific directory structure and the configurations are not located within a direct ancestor directory. In that case it is proabably preferable to omit the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation. In order to tell Spring to still auto-configure Camel you can simply pass `CamelAutoConfiguration.class` to the classes mentioned in `@SpringBootTest`

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE, classes = {
    Route1.class,
    Route2.class,
    RouteTest.Config.class,
    CamelAutoConfiguration.class
}
```

As no automatic configuration is performed, Spring won't load the test configuration inside your test class nor initialize Camel as well. By adding those configs to the boot classes manually Spring will do it for you.

Comment: `@DisableJmx` does not disable JMX, because test is marked to run with `SpringRunner`, not `CamelSpringRunner`.

Comment: @realmfoo thanks for the hint. I'm updating the post

Comment: do you know how to use properties with this setup? I'm looking at their page here: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/spring-testing.html#SpringTesting-CamelEnhancedSpringTest and they reference UseOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent ?

Comment: @RyuS. Have you tried adding `@PropertySource("classpath:some.properties")` to your config class?

Comment: @RyuS. Also, [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745168/how-to-test-classes-with-configurationproperties-and-autowired) might be of interest to you

Comment: I am getting `NoSuchEndpointException` with a Spring Boot test. @RomanVottner, What could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: @ddsultan Sorry for being late to answer, but I somehow  missed your question. That exception indicates usually that one of the endpoints you've defined is not existing. I.e. if you copied the templated 1:1 you defined a route with a direct consumer with the name `someEndpoint` but the template targets a direct consumer with the name `start` which is of course not defined in this template.

Answer (score 4):

For one route with MQ and Spring Boot like this:

```java
    @Component
    public class InboundRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
      @Override
      public void configure() {
        JaxbDataFormat personDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat();
        personDataFormat.setContextPath(Person.class.getPackage().getName());
        personDataFormat.setPrettyPrint(true);
        from("direct:start").id("InboundRoute")
            .log("inbound route")
            .marshal(personDataFormat)
            .to("log:com.company.app?showAll=true&multiline=true")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .inOnly("mq:q.empi.deim.in")
            .transform(constant("DONE"));
      }
    }
```

I use [adviceWith](https://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) in order to replace the endpoint and use only mocks:

```java
    @RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
    @UseAdviceWith
    @SpringBootTest(classes = InboundApp.class)
    @MockEndpoints("mock:a")
    public class InboundRouteCamelTest {
    
      @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:a")
      private MockEndpoint mock;
    
      @Produce(uri = "direct:start")
      private ProducerTemplate template;
    
      @Autowired
      private CamelContext context;
    
      @Test
      public void whenInboundRouteIsCalled_thenSuccess() throws Exception {
        mock.expectedMinimumMessageCount(1);
        RouteDefinition route = context.getRouteDefinition("InboundRoute");
        route.adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
          @Override
          public void configure() {
            weaveByToUri("mq:q.empi.deim.in").replace().to("mock:a");
          }
        });
        context.start();
    
        String response = (String) template.requestBodyAndHeader("direct:start",
            getSampleMessage("/SimplePatient.xml"), Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    
        assertThat(response).isEqualTo("DONE");
        mock.assertIsSatisfied();
      }
    
      private String getSampleMessage(String filename) throws Exception {
        return IOUtils
            .toString(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
      }
    }
```

I use the following dependencies: Spring Boot 2.1.4-RELEASE and Camel 2.23.2. The complete source code is available on [Github](https://github.com/earth001/advanced_camel_homework_assignment).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Camel test runner?

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

If you are using `camel-spring-boot` dependency, you may know that it uses auto configuration to setup Camel:

```
CamelAutoConfiguration.java
```

It means that you may also need to add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to your test.

Comment: Hi,   CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner is deprecated. I got it working with something like this. 
`public class AmqTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new ActiveMqConfig().route();
    }`