# Loading test application.yml properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, configurationproperties

I have a test properties file under `src/test/resources/application.yml`.  But I cannot get the values to load in my unit test.  I have the following class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("snmp")
open class SnmpProperties {

    var port: Int = 1611
    lateinit var protocol: String
    lateinit var host: String

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "SnmpProperties(port=$port, protocol='$protocol', host='$host')"
    }
}
```

which in the production code, loads in the values from `/src/main/resources/application.yml`.

```
snmp:
  port: 1161
  protocol: udp
  host: 0.0.0.0
```

Unit test class:

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
open class SnmpRouteTest : CamelTestSupport() {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var snmpProperties: SnmpProperties

    @Mock
    lateinit var repository: IPduEventRepository

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var snmpTrapRoute: SnmpTrapRoute

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        initMocks(this)
    }
```

I have tried to add a `test` profile to each `application.yml` files to see if that adding `@ActiveProfiles("test")` worked, but it didn't.

**src/main/resources/application.yml &
src/test/resources/application.yml**

```
# Test profile
spring:
  profiles: test
snmp:
  port: 1161
  protocol: udp
  host: 0.0.0.0
```

I've also created a TestConfiguration class which creates the `SnmpProperties` bean and autowire it into the test class using `@EnableConfigurationProperties(TestConfiguration::class)`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SnmpProperties::class)
open class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    open fun snmpProperties() = SnmpProperties()
}
```

Again, no go.  The error I get is:

```
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'snmpTrapRoute' of type 'class org.meanwhile.in.hell.camel.snmp.receiver.route.SnmpRoute'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : Parameter specified as non-null is null: method org.meanwhile.in.hell.camel.snmp.receiver.route.SnmpTrapRoute.<init>, parameter snmpProperties
```

Comment: you can overried the data that you want to use in test profile and put it in application-test.yml !

Comment: Thats what I've tried.  I've updated my question to make this clearer.

Comment: try to see this : https://tuhrig.de/testing-configurationproperties-in-spring-boot/
or https://stackoverflow.com/a/31748450/4373948

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @D.B I have added my re-written unit test as an answer below.  Its Camel specific.  Instead of loading test properties, I replaced the "real" route with a dummy route, so production properties were loaded as normal.  Took me a while to figure it out, but i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check your project structure. The properties file should be on the classpath in order for Spring Boot to find and use it.
For example the project structure as defined by Maven here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

In case of Maven your configuration files should be put in these directories:

```
src/main/resources/application.yml
src/test/resources/application.yml
```

Comment: Sorry, I'd made a mistake in my question around the true path to my YML files.  I've corrected the layout.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bean is not created (hence the null error).

Try to either:

- add `@Configuration` on top of your SnmpProperties configuration class
- add `@EnableConfigurationProperties(SnmpProperties.class)` on top of your test class

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = [SnmpTrapReceiverCamelApplication::class])
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@DisableJmx(false)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class SnmpTrapRouteTest {

    object TestSnmpConstants {
        const val SNMP_REAL_ENDPOINT_ID = "snmp-trap-route"
        const val SNMP_DIRECT_REPLACEMENT_ENDPOINT = "direct:snmp-from"
        const val TRAP_REQUEST_ID = 123456789
        const val TRAP_OID = "1.2.3.4.5"
        const val TRAP_PAYLOAD = "snmp-trap-payload"
    }

    @MockBean
    lateinit var repository: IPduEventRepository

    @Produce
    lateinit var producerTemplate: ProducerTemplate

    @Autowired
    lateinit var camelContext: CamelContext

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun `Should call save method on the repository when PDU TRAP event supplied`() {

        // Replace our SNMP consumer route with a dummy route than can be called from a producer internally.
        // Since our snmp endpoint is an asynchronous consumer (meaning it only receives data from external events)
        // we need to use the "direct:" component to allow a producer to internally call what is ordinarily an external
        // event-driven endpoint.  Otherwise we will get a Connection Refused error, as we cannot access the external
        // system/socket.
        AdviceWithRouteBuilder.adviceWith(camelContext, TestSnmpConstants.SNMP_REAL_ENDPOINT_ID) { routeBuilder ->
            routeBuilder.replaceFromWith(TestSnmpConstants.SNMP_DIRECT_REPLACEMENT_ENDPOINT)
        }

        // Create the PDU object to send to the SNMP endpoint
        val trap = PDU()
        trap.type = PDU.TRAP
        trap.requestID = Integer32(TestSnmpConstants.TRAP_REQUEST_ID)
        trap.add(VariableBinding(OID(TestSnmpConstants.TRAP_OID), OctetString(TestSnmpConstants.TRAP_PAYLOAD)))

        // "direct:" endpoints only send DefaultMessage objects.  These are not castable to SnmpMessage objects,
        // so need to overwrite the exchange IN message to be an SnmpMessage object
        val exchange = DefaultExchange(camelContext)
        exchange.setIn(SnmpMessage(camelContext, trap))

        // ProducerTemplates need a default endpoint specified.
        // The ProducerTemplate provides us with a producer that can directly deliver messages to consumers defined
        // in the camelContext, using the "direct:" component (see above)
        producerTemplate.setDefaultEndpointUri(TestSnmpConstants.SNMP_DIRECT_REPLACEMENT_ENDPOINT)
        producerTemplate.send(exchange)

        // Verify that the repository.save() was invoked
        verify(repository, atLeast(1)).save(any())
    }
}
```