# Mocking a constructor which sets member variables using other member variables whose configurable values are read from properties file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit4, powermock

I have a spring mvc application. There is a class A as shown below:

```
public class A extends X {

    private final RetryRegistry retryReg;

    @value("${retry.attempts:5}")
    private int retryAttempts;

    @value("${retry.delay:5000}")
    private int retryDelay;

    public A( B b, C c, D d){
        super(b,c,d);
        
        this.retryReg = RetryRegistry.of(RetryConfig.custom()
                         .maxAttempts(this.retryAttempts)   
                         .waitDuration(Duration.ofMillis(this.retryDelay))
                         .build());
    }
    
    .......
}
```

The test class for class A is as shown below:

```
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
@runWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@SupressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ATest {

    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

........

}
```

Now when test class injects mock and calls A's constructor, the value for retryAttempts is 0 inside the constructor, hence an exception is thrown.

It seems that the configurable properties (from the properties file whose path has been mentioned in servlet-context are no being read) when inject mock tries to construct A.

I tried many things like adding @TestPropertySource to my test file, but it doesn't work.

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:SettingsTest.properties")
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
@runWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@SupressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ATest {

    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

........

}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is @TestPropertySource is only supported for Springboot apps.
Any suggestions on how I can set the configurable properties before @InjectMocks tries to access class A'constructor.

Comment: The `@ConfigurationProperties` are supposed to be attached to classes with members representing the config values, and in the operational code, not the test code. Have you read a tutorial on them?

Comment: @daniu the accepted answer in this thread uses it in test class
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745168/how-to-test-classes-with-configurationproperties-and-autowired

Comment: @daniu: thanks for pointing out, I mentioned the wrong annotation

Comment: ConfigurationProperties are the solution to your problem though, you can easily mock them. Or do you need the values in a file? Not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

How about you create the registry as a bean in a `@Configuration`?

```
// this will automatically be initialized with yours properties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="retry)
class RetryProperties {
    private int attempts;
    private int delay;
}
@Configuration
class RetryConfiguration {
    @Bean RetryRegistry registry(RetryProperties props) {
        return RetryRegistry.of(RetryConfig.custom()
                 .maxAttempts(retryProperties)
                 .waitDuration(Duration.ofMillis(this.retryDelay))
                 .build());
    }
}
@Component // I assume, otherwise the @Value properties wouldn't work
public class A extends X {
    private final RetryRegistry retryReg;

    public A( B b, C c, D d, RetryRegistry reg){
        super(b,c,d);
        this.retryReg = reg;
    }
    .......
}
```

Now you can mock and inject the registry.

Overall, your structure looks a bit all over the place, with some constructor autowiring, some initialization in the constructor, some fields read from properties. You should probably stick to one of them. Also `super(b,c,d)` looks pretty suspicious, I've rarely seen a class hierarchy be a good idea for components (with three parameters no less).