# Using Spring Boot 1.2 YAML configuration

Tags: spring-boot

I have an application with Spring Boot 1.2 and I need to use YAML configuration.
I tried following settings:

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
```

**application.yml**

```
foo:
  bar: baz
```

**FooProperties**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
public class FooProperties {

  private String bar;
  
  // getters, setters, equals etc.
```

**FooPropertiesConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FooProperties.class)
public class FooPropertiesConfig {
}
```

**FooPropertiesTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = FooProperties.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = FooProperties.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class FooPropertiesTest extends TestCase {

    @Autowired
    private FooProperties tested;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final String bar = tested.getBar();

        assertEquals("baz", bar);
    }
}
```

But *bar* is always null. What am I missing?

EDIT1:
I tried to use old-fashion *application.properties* but the result is the same.

EDIT2:

I've created endpoint and it works. Problem seems to be only in my test configuration.

```
@RestController
public class FooController {

    @Autowired
    private FooProperties fooProperties;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String foo() {
        return "Hello World: " + fooProperties.getBar();
    }
}
```

**Result:** Hello World: baz

Comment: Maybe create a mock project with a more recent Spring Boot version and make that work. You should remove class `FooPropertiesConfig `, and @ContextConfiguration(classes = FooProperties.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = FooProperties.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.yml") and use @ActiveProfiles in your tests. It will require you to specify profiles in your application.yml

Comment: I think the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745168/how-to-test-classes-with-configurationproperties-and-autowired) will help you.