# Issues with test execution with @ConfigurationProperties usage in java sbring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, unit-testing, configurationproperties

Context is getting passed as null, hence getting NullPointerException in context.getBean("abcRestTemplate", RestTemplate.class). What can be the issue for context to be null.

AuthnConfig.java

```
@Getter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "authn")
@Configuration
public class AuthnConfig {

    @Value("${endpoint}")
    private String endpoint;

    @Value("${client-svc.name}")
    private String serviceClientId;
}
```

RestTemplateConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    private final AuthnConfig authnConfig;

    @Autowired
    public RestTemplateConfig(final AuthnConfig authnConfig) {
        this.authnConfig = authnConfig;
    }

    @Bean(name = "abcRestTemplate"){
    public RestTemplate abcRestTemplate() {
        //authConfig.getEndpoint() etc....
    }
   }
}
```

RestTemplateConfigTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class RestTemplateConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplateConfig restTemplateConfig;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Mock
    private AuthnConfig authnConfig;

    @Before
    public void initializeConfig() {
        Mockito.when(authnConfig.getEndpoint()).thenReturn("https://localhost");
    }

    @Test
    public void testForBeanCreation() {
        RestTemplate abcRestTemplate = context.getBean("abcRestTemplate", RestTemplate.class);
        assertNotNull(abcRestTemplate);
    }
}
```

Errors If @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) is used in RestTemplateConfigTest.class:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException, context is getting passed as NULL in context.getBean("abcRestTemplate", RestTemplate.class);
```

Errors If @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) is used in RestTemplateConfigTest.class

```
[ERROR] testForBeanCreation  Time elapsed: 0.028 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authnConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'endpoint' in value "${endpoint}"
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'endpoint' in value "${endpoint}"
```

Comment: May be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745168/how-to-test-classes-with-configurationproperties-and-autowired

Comment: This won't work. The `@Before` method is called after the context is initialized and thus the beans have already been created and at that point the value is `null`. You might try `@MockBean` so the actual bean is replaced but still the `@Before` will be executed too late to make a difference.

Comment: Here i am checking if bean is created or not, do i still need to add @MockBean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the your SpringBooltApplication.class to this @SpringBootTest Annotation, just like this: @SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootApplicationDemo.class)