# How to test that Spring Boot does *not* start if datasource creation failed

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-test

Is there a way to write unit tests to make sure spring boot API doesn't get started if a certain bean is failed to create. eg: failing to create datasource bean.

Comment: Spring Boot won't start at all if bean creation failed to create unless there is conditional handling. Do you want to override the bean definition in the unit test in order to achieve that?

Comment: the requirement is to write tests to make sure spring boot won't start if bean creation is failed, is there any way of accomplishing that?

Comment: If you wanted to check for a certain bean, you can make a test like example 7 at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing and Autowire the desired bean into your test, then assert it is not null. Alternatively, you could hit the /beans endpoint and check for the bean by name. But, this is testing the Spring framework not your code. You should question why this is a require because it sounds like a miscommunication. If you are trying to write a test that proves it is impossible for the server to start without a bean ever, it is impossible. Tests can prove bugs, but not the absence of bugs.

Comment: Can you create a minimal (if needed synthetic) example for the problem you are having?

Comment: Thanks all for the helpful responses, I was able to find a solution using this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692863/what-is-the-best-way-to-test-that-a-spring-application-context-fails-to-start

Answer (score 0):

This code should do it for you:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AnyAppNameApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

From the docs:

> Annotation that can be specified on a test class that runs Spring Boot
>   based tests. Provides the following features over and above the
>   regular Spring TestContext Framework:
>
> - Uses SpringBootContextLoader as the default ContextLoader when no specific `@ContextConfiguration(loader=...)` is defined.
> - Automatically searches for a `@SpringBootConfiguration` when nested `@Configuration` is not used, and no explicit classes are specified.
> - Allows custom Environment properties to be defined using the properties attribute.
> - Provides support for different webEnvironment modes, including the ability to start a fully running web server listening on a defined or
>     random port.
> - Registers a TestRestTemplate and/or WebTestClient bean for use in web tests that are using a fully running web server.
>
> If you are using JUnit 4, don’t forget to also add
>   `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to your test, otherwise the annotations
>   will be ignored. If you are using JUnit 5, there’s no need to add the
>   equivalent `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension)` as `@SpringBootTest` and the
>   other `@…Test` annotations are already annotated with it.